# Angular Server-Side Rendering with Route Resolve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to use Server-Side Rendering in Angular (v4) to allow for better SEO.

Things work as expected until I add `resolve` on my route. Adding `resolve` causes HTML `title` to retain it's initial value when viewing source.

**My Module:**

```
import {
  Injectable,
  ModuleWithProviders,
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Resolve,
  Router,
  RouterModule,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {
  ArticleComponent
} from './article.component';
import {
  Article,
  ArticlesService,
  UserService,
  SharedModule
} from '../shared';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleResolver implements Resolve < Article > {
  constructor(
    private articlesService: ArticlesService,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): any {
    return this.articlesService.get(route.params['slug'])
      .catch((err) => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'));
  }
}

const articleRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([{
  path: 'article/:slug',
  component: ArticleComponent,
  resolve: {
     article: ArticleResolver
  },
  data: {
    preload: true
  }
}]);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    articleRouting,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ArticleComponent
  ],

  providers: [
    ArticleResolver
  ]
}) export class ArticleModule {}
```

**My Component:**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Title,
  Meta
} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {
  AppComponent
} from '../app.component';

import {
  Article,
} from '../shared';

@Component({
  selector: 'article-page',
  templateUrl: './article.component.html'
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  article: Article;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private meta: Meta,
    private title: Title
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(
      (data: {
        article: Article
      }) => {
        this.article = data.article;
      }
    );
    this.title.setTitle(this.article.title);
  }
}
```

I am new to Angular SSR so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my primary service was referencing a secondary service that was attempting to return an authentication token from `window.localStorage`.

Attempting to access the client storage caused Angular SSR to omit the generation of source code for my component.

Thanks [@Adam_P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6452360/adam-p) for helping me walk through it!

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. My site is running on SSR so that I can generate source code for SEO + facebook. If I use resolver then I do not get any of these tags in my  'View Source'.  My service is passing auth token from localstorage with condition =>  (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)). Could you please let me know how did you resolve your issue?  I need all meta tags so as to work FB share link.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of subscribing to route data, retrieve your results from the snapshot like this:

`this.route.snapshot.data['article']`

You also might need to register `ArticlesService` in your `providers` for the module.

As a side note, this import:

```
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

is an RxJS antipattern. Please use the following import instead:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: I've added all three suggested changes but am still receiving the same issue. However, I am receiving a 'ReferenceError: window is not defined' on the server log when navigate to an article's route.

Comment: Now that I looked more into it, that error does not seem to be related. Anyway, I'm assuming it is generating the source code asynchronously before pulling the article from the service and rendering it. If this is the case, is there anyway I can force the source code generation to wait until the article is pulled?

Comment: The point of resolve is to wait before rendering the component until it is complete. Try printing out what the snapshot is to make sure you're getting data correctly in the component. I updated the answer to reflect how to do this.

Comment: The snapshot is returning the data correctly within the component. Also, using `this.article = this.route.snapshot.data['article'];` `this.title.setTitle(this.article.title);` does not affect the source code being rendered.